# Migrate Rhythmbox music library, especially amount of times played and starring

Tags: rhythmbox, music-player

I am struggling to migrate my music library. Apparently the starring and the amount of times read are not stored within the files but in an XML file, which I was able to localise, but I don't know how to do something with it. Is there a way to convert this information according to some standard sothat other applications could use it easily ?

Comment: This has been a long standing feature request.